# PHP pass by reference in recursive function not working

Tags: php, recursion, pass-by-reference

I have two functions that I'm using to add or remove slashes from a deeply nested object/array combo. The first "level" of the array is always an object, but some of its properties may be arrays or objects.

Here are my two functions:

```
function objSlash( &$obj, $add=true )
{
    foreach ( $obj as $key=>$field )
    {
        if ( is_object( $field ) )
            objSlash( $field, $add );
        else if ( is_array( $field ) )
            arrSlash( $field, $add );
        else if ( $add )
            $obj->$key = addslashes( $field );
        else
            $obj->$key = stripslashes( $field );
    }

    return;
}

function arrSlash( &$arr, $add=true )
{
    foreach ( $arr as $key=>$field )
    {
        if ( is_object( $field ) )
            objSlash( $field, $add );
        else if ( is_array( $field ) )
            arrSlash( $field, $add );
        else if ( $add )
            $arr[$key] = addslashes( $field );
        else
            $arr[$key] = stripslashes( $field );
    }

    return;
}
```

Being called like so:

```
objSlash( $obj, false );
```

However, the function does not strip the slashes from the nested array. The object passed into the function is like this:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 3
    [lines] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [character] => Name
                    [dialogue] => Something including \"quotes\"
                )
        )
)
```

What have I done wrong? Somewhere along the line a reference is going missing...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`foreach`](http://docs.php.net/foreach) uses a copy of the array/object and not the array/object itself:

> **Note:** Unless the array is [referenced](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php), `foreach` operates on a copy of the specified array and not the array itself. `foreach` has some side effects on the array pointer. Don't rely on the array pointer during or after the `foreach` without resetting it.

So use either a reference:

```
foreach ($arr as $key => &$field) {
    // …
}
```

Or use the array element/object property itself like Kuroki Kaze suggested by using `$arr[$key]` instead of its copied value `$field`.

Answer (score 2):

`foreach` makes a copy of value, i suppose.

Try using `objSlash( $arr[$key], $add )` intead of `objSlash( $field, $add )` inside `foreach`.

Comment: I think you meant: objSlash( $arr[$key], $add )